# What is the modern consensus on the difficulty of infinitesimals?

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, model-theory, mathematical-philosophy, nonstandard-analysis

At a related [thread at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602977) an expert in reverse mathematics noted that "As the modern consensus is that only nonstandard models have infinitesimals, it will be quite challenging to give a concrete example of one."  Such a challenge of giving concrete examples of infinitesimals would presumably also apply to infinite numbers.

I find this difficult to understand because if one has weak theories like Peano Arithmetic in mind, Skolem already constructed explicit models in 1933, in particular without relying on the axiom of choice.  This was analyzed in detail by Stillwell in his article in the 1970s; see e.g., [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=465766).

Meanwhile, if one aims for the full power of the transfer principle as in Robinson's framework then an infinite integer $H$ would immediately produce nonmeasurable objects like $\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}:H\in{}^{\ast}\!A\}$ so that a construction would be of difficulty comparable to Banach-Tarski and the like.

What is the *nontrivial* logical content of an assertion that infinite numbers are hard to come by, in the sense of reverse mathematics, perhaps in reference to theories of intermediate strength?

Comment: The motivation for the thread on math.SE seems to have been pedagogical: if one is teaching freshman calculus using an approach similar to Keisler's, how does one describe this issue to the students? In that context, I think the answer is clear. The students are learning a body of practices for manipulating infinitesimals, and these practices have been standardized and in use by scientists and engineers without interruption since Leibniz and Newton. In that body of standard practices, we never distinguish an individual infinitesimal.

Comment: This question misunderstands Carl Mummert's remark, which is not saying much more than that there are no infinitesimals in the standard model of first-order PA. This fact does not imply any sweeping statement such as "infinite numbers are hard to come by" or that there is a "difficulty of giving concrete examples of infinitesimals." For example, in the context of surreal numbers (rather than nonstandard analysis), one can give concrete definitions of certain infinitesimals as being the values of certain finite games. The question should be rephrased to eliminate false presuppositions.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I tried to be even more precise about the comment concerning the challenge of giving concrete examples.

Comment: katz, you should ask Carl Mummert to clarify his comment on MSE before asking this question. At the risk of additionally stirring muddy waters, there are no computable nonstandard models of PA: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tennenbaum's_theorem

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, I am aware of Tennenbaum's theorem but recursive issues are not necessarily the only yardstick in modern mathematics and Skolem's construction is completely explicit, taking place in ZF (with no reliance on choice), as explained in Stillwell's article. A number of editors have expressed an interest in this question (namely, 8) and I hope to get some interesting answers; there does not seem to be any reason why this should be limited to a discussion with a particular editor.

Comment: Being not a fan of surreals, is it that number system in which sqrt(2) is rational (surrational whatever) ?

Comment: @VladimirKanovei, you could include a note Timothy to indicate that your question is addressed to Chow.

Comment: ...I mean @TimothyChow

Comment: katz, the question is specifically about Carl Mummert's comment. He's in an ideal position to clarify what he meant. For what it's worth, my reading of Mummert's comment is similar to Tim's. Nothing is being said about the difficulty of finding non-standard _models_, it's only said that non-standard _numbers_ may be hard to find since, according to common belief, one model has no non-standard numbers.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, based on your *reputations* both you and Carl are eminently qualified to reopen this thread so that such an answer can be posted here; note that you have not addressed my remark that a number of editors seem interested in this question so that there does not seem to be a reason to limit the discussion to a specific editor. MathOverflow is better suited for this particular discussion because it is clearly closer to a discussion among professional mathematicians rather than a topic in the calculus etc.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei No. They're Conway's extension of the ordinals; $\omega-1$, $\sqrt\omega$, and $\frac1{\omega}$ make no sense as ordinals, but the surreals give meaning to these expressions. They form a proper class (since they contain the ordinals as a subclass), and every ordered field is a subclass of the surreals. In any case, $\sqrt2$ is still not rational.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei I'm not sure if exponentiation is well-defined for the surreals, but addition and multiplication are (making it a proper-class field).

Comment: As far as infinite numbers are concerned, there does exist a way of using omega to build them, but the surreals are a fairly weak theory. This theory is not suitable for doing either calculus or analysis because it lacks even a weak form of the transfer principle. You may have noticed I have been "advertizing" Skolem's arithmetic which is insufficiently known. The advantage here is that you don't use the axiom of choice, and there is a fairly good transfer principle though not as strong as in Robinson's framework...

Comment: ...The main point is that the idea of construction is the same, i.e., you use sequences up a suitable equivalence relation to get infinite numbers eventually. Skolem was primarily interested in arithmetic so he only worked with infinite numbers, but if you form the quotient field you get infinitesimals as well. These can actually be used to develop a significant fragment of calculus though certainly not everything since one lacks completeness, Skolem's system being countable. @AkivaWeinberger

Comment: katz, since you have yet to ask Carl Mummert to clarify his statement on MSE and you have yet to consider the possibility that you might have misunderstood what he wrote, there is no cause to reopen this question.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, I have great respect both for Carl and you but you are still not relating to my point that, apart from whatever Carl may have meant or not meant, the issue I raised caught the interest of at least 9 editors in the space of less than 24 hours who upvoted the question, and may lead to interesting answers without need to squeeze them into *comments* in smaller installments (as I had to do above).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, OK, I did (see there).

Comment: What Skolem arithmetic are you referring to? Unless I'm missing something, it's a nonstandard model of arithmetic, the existence of which depends on the compactness theorem, which is equivalent to a weak form of the axiom of choice… right? (Also, your link doesn't work for me.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Because the language of arithmetic is countable, there is no need for the full compactness theorem, one only needs the compactness theorem for countable languages which is equivalent to the _Weak_ König Lemma and provable in ZF.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Ah, thanks. (Note: I know almost nothing about logic. I took a two-day course on the compactness theorem over the summer and that's about it.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, thanks for your comment.  It should be pointed out that this does not seem to be how Skolem constructed his model, or at least I have never seen such a claim in the literature (if this is true I would be very interested in seeing the details). Rather, he used sequences of (finite) integers, in a construction that can be thought of as a constructive analogue of the ultrapower though of course he did not use any (even weak) form of choice.

Comment: Everything I know about Skolem's model can be found in section 3.2 of our article here:   http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-012-9316-5 also available on the arxiv.

Comment: So much commentary might have been avoided by simply sending me an email! I left a follow-up comment on Jan. 7 at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602977/whats-an-example-of-an-infinitesimal?noredirect=1#comment3267855_1603411 which explains what I mean. // I think the phrase "infinitesimal number" has some ambiguity.   It seems possible to give a (more or less) concrete example of an ordered field containing infinitesimals and "infinite" elements.  However, it isn't clear that such objects are infinite *numbers* - is the term "number" often used for an element of an arbitrary field?

Comment: @katz: Please see my previous comment. Regarding this question, the usual way we would look at nonstandard analysis in Reverse Mathematics is to look at conservation theorems which say "if a theorem of such and such syntactic form is provable in this particular system of axioms for nonstandard analysis then the theorem is also provable in that particular standard system".   Many results have been obtained. We don't normally look at theorems which say "a model of such and such system of nonstandard analysis exists", for various reasons.

Comment: One of the simplest examples of an ordered field with infinite/infinitesimal elements is the field of rational functions over the real numbers, ordered by growth at infinity (i.e., $f < g$ if $f(x) < g(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$). This is awfully well known. See for example here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hbe/resource/general/131a.3.06w/nonArchimedian.pdf Thus $x$, which eventually exceeds any constant/standard real, is an infinite, and $1/x$ is an infinitesimal in this ordered field.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, note that $\sqrt{2}$ is indeed surrational, showing that the surreals do not satisfy a transfer principle, as per user Vladimir Kanovei.

Comment: @katz Oh, by "surrational" you meant "ratio of omnific integers." That makes sense (even though Googling "surrational" does not give this definition). …I could pretend to be smart and say that I assumed "surrational" meant "with a terminating continued fraction, where the continued fraction is generated by omnific integer part rather than integer part," but I didn't actually know this at the time; I just read about it now. (Apparently, it's what Conway thought the best analogue of rational numbers should be in the surreals, despite the fact that they're neither closed by sum nor by products.)

Comment: @katz (But, yeah, "surrational" doesn't seem to be an actual term.)

Comment: Regarding this search for surrationals, the point is that surreals are field-isomorphic to a certain class-size saturated version of *R, which contains *N and *Q, of course, and the mentioned isomorphism induces "true" surnaturals and surrationals within surreals. The great issue is therefore how to detect those "true" surnaturals and surrationals in surreals

Comment: @katz: Just because $\sqrt{2}$ (just as every surreal number) is the quotient of two omnific integers doesn't mean $No$ can't satisfy a tranfer principle over $\mathbb{R}$: it just means that if it can, then $^*\mathbb{Z}$ can't be the ring of omnific integers.

Comment: @Vladimir Kaovei: Where can one find a proof of your claim? I read an article of P.Ehrlich where he discusses his method (as well with Keisler) to prove that but details were not provided.

Comment: @nombre, does Ehrlich claim that the surrationals do satisfy a transfer?

Comment: @Katz: What do you mean by the surrationnals? In *The absolute arithmetic continuum [...]*, Ehrlich refers to Keisler and suggests that his method to produce a "model of NSA" using innaccessible cardinals can be adapted to produce a class-sized definable model of NSA in NBG. 

You'll find a simplified construction of a definable ordered field with transfer principle in Keisler's *Foundations of Infinitesimal Calculus*.

Comment: @nombre, I agree with you that the hyperreals possess a transfer principle :-)  The question is whether the surreals do.  In particular, the ordinary integers and the ordinary rational numbers are related by the property that each rational is a ratio of two integers. If transfer held over the surreals, a similar property would have to relate the surrationals and the surintegers. Does it?

Comment: @katz! I forgot to say: such class-sized model of NSA would be isomorphic to the Field of surreal numbers (Ehrlich proved this, and this is because Keisler imposes that the class satisfies a "saturation principle")

If by surrinteger you mean the natural extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ and by surrationnal you mean the natural extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ then yes of course it does (assuming Keisler and Ehrlich's "results" are true). Note that the reis no reason why $^*\mathbb{Z}$ should be the ring of omnific integers.

Comment: @nombre, as mentioned elsewhere at MO, Ehrlich did not actually prove his Theorem 20 in that paper.  The theorem seems to be due to Keisler.  Granted that by exploiting the isomorphism between the maximal surreals and the maximal hyperreals, one can also export an isomorphic copy of the transfer principle over to the surreals, at which point it becomes interesting to determine what the "true" surintegers and the "true" surrationals are (namely, the isomorphic image of the hyperintegers and the hyperrationals), which as Vladimir pointed out above seems to be an open problem.

Comment: Ehrlich did prove theorem 20 assuming Kesiler's work can be adapted to class-sized structures in NBG. 
Now, I don't know about the difficulty of finding hyperintegers in $No$. I think no one at the present time has found a way to define an  integer part $Z$ of $No$ such that $(No,Z,+,.,0,1,<)$ is an elementary extension of $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z},+,.,0,1,<)$.

Comment: @nombre, that does limit the usefulness of the surreals/surintegers in analysis, doesn't it?

Comment: @katz: In non standard analysis maybe, but it is rather a lack of knowledge than a limitation.

Comment: @nombre, I don't know what you mean.  In order to do analysis you require at least a rudimentary form of the transfer principle.  If you can't even have an elementary extension, how are you going to define a simple function like sine over the surreals?

Comment: @katz: What do you mean by "doing analysis"? Is doing analysis defining an ordered field with a definable transfer principle over the real numbers? If so, why not just say that?

Comment: @nombre, no, doing analysis means doing calculus first, and you can't do calculus unless you define at least all the elementary functions on the extended field.  We need transfer to get the extensions and not vice versa.  Applications come first, theory later.

Comment: @katz: Your answer is basically "No; well... yes". In any case, so far, no such thing has been done for the field of surreal numbers. (though it has an extension of the exponential map)
There are some instances of study of analytic properties of $No$. The work of Ehrlich is the only one I know of which tries to establish links between the surreal numbers and non-standart analysis.

Comment: @nombre, I have great respect for Ehrlich's work, both his historical work (see his influential paper on the history of non-archimedean mathematics) and his work on the surreals. I am not entirely sure how relevant the surreals are to calculus/analysis, but even if they are not they remain a valid field of research, so you certainly have nothing to apologize for. I think saying that Robinson's framework is more relevant when it comes to analysis is a noncontroversial statement.  Actually, this discussion may well have the seeds of an interesting MO question...  What do you think?

Comment: @katz: I don't think speaking in subjective non mathematical terms help us understand mathematical objects. $No$ isn't a good field for teaching calculus since we don't know whether $No$ has well-behaved analytic functions but what's the point of speculating? Recently, there have been advances in the study of the Hardy-field structure of $No$ and this could be useful to solve some differential equations. Why speculate? If you have a question to ask feel free to do it and I will take part in the discussion provided I have something to say.

Comment: @nombre, I don't recall using the term "speculation".  MO is not a site for "discussion" but rather for asking specific questions. Any MO question relating to the surreals and hyperreals would have to respect the MO guidelines.

Comment: With regard to comment by @Timothy Chow Jan 8 at 16:53:
Surreals are disqualified as a source of infinitesimals because they don't form a true model of calculus (do not contain true infinite natural numbers and many more)

Comment: @VladimirKanovei : I agree that surreals are inappropriate as a vehicle for formalizing arguments in calculus that appeal to infinitesimals, but my point was that the question as phrased makes sweeping assumptions about infinitesimals (e.g., that the only context in which the term "infinitesimal" arises is in calculus) that are unwarranted.

Comment: @Timothy, I mentioned neither calculus nor analysis in my *question*. If you have constructive suggestions as to how the question could be improved, please put them forward.

Comment: @katz : As Carl Mummert has already clarified his comment, I don't think there's much to be gained by tinkering with the question at this stage. I agree that you didn't mention calculus or analysis; that is my point, actually. Citing a discussion about nonstandard analysis but then framing the question as a general question about "infinite numbers" without qualification is rather confusing.  But we're beating a dead horse.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty involved in developing a theory of infinitesimals that would be useful in analysis is illustrated by the fact that, as discussed in the *comments* above, the surreals are unsuitable for this task. Classically one can produce nonstandard models of the integers in ZF, as discussed at related *questions*, but in a constructive context it does not seem particularly easy to prove a compactness theorem that would have similar ramifications.  So perhaps a constructive context is an example of such "intermediate difficulty".